# How to retrieve details for a particular id from MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Getting data from the database depending on the value of the id in the URL.

```
$id= $_GET['id'];
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE id='$id'";
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
```

This is working, But it's displaying a blank page.

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Do you have anything else on that page? Could be a php error causing blank page.

Comment: You need to use a loop in order to fetch the data, then echo it. (*So, who wants to go for it*)?

Comment: Take a look at http://us3.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc

Comment: ^--« Please don't do that. Post it (*code*) in your question, not in the "comment" box. @user3435833

Comment: I think you are beginning to learn mysql extensions in php. This is the right time to upgrade, as mysql() function will be soon deprecated in later version of PHP. So better start  with mysqli or PDO's in PHP. Linkz are given in the answer provided by @tchow002

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my original comment:

*"You need to use a loop in order to fetch the data, then echo it."*

Others have given you examples and not to use your present method, here is a PDO method:

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = 'xxx';
$mysql_username = 'xxx';
$mysql_password = 'xxx';
$mysql_dbname = 'xxx';

$id = $_GET['id'];

try {

$pdo= new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password); 
     $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
     exit( $e->getMessage() );
}


try {

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM people WHERE id = :id');
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();

} catch (PDOException $e) {
     echo $e->getMessage();
}

/* optional method
foreach($stmt as $row) {
      echo $row['id'] . ' ' . $row['name'] . ' ' . $row['email'];
}
*/

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $id = $row['id'];
  $n = $row['name'];
  $e = $row['email'];
}

echo $id;
echo "<br>";
echo $n;
echo "<br>";
echo $e;

?>
```

---

Another PDO method:

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = 'xxx';
$mysql_username = 'xxx';
$mysql_password = 'xxx';
$mysql_dbname = 'xxx';

$id = $_GET['id'];

// $id= 4; // my own test id number

try {

$pdo= new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password); 
     $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
     exit( $e->getMessage() );
}

try {
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE id='$id'";
     $results = $pdo->query($sql);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
     echo $e->getMessage();
}

/* optional method
foreach($results as $row) {
      echo $row['id'] . ' ' . $row['name'] . ' ' . $row['email'];
}
*/

while ($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $id = $row['id'];
  $n = $row['name'];
  $e = $row['email'];
}

echo $id;
echo "<br>";
echo $n;
echo "<br>";
echo $e;

?>
```

Comment: You're quite welcome, glad I could help. @user3435833 If you feel this answered your question, consider clicking the White (grayed outline) checkmark/tick till it turns Green, in case you're not aware of how the StackOverflow systems works :) This closes the question properly. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

[1]. `mysql_*` is deprecated.

[2]. Your code is VERY vulnerable to sql injection. Sanitize `$_GET['id']` with `mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])` (`mysqli` if you update to that)

[3]. The results are returned as resources. Loop through it with:

```
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) { echo $r['someField']; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using **[mysql_query](https://www.php.net/mysql_query)** since it is deprecated.

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future.

I recommend using **[MySQLi](https://www.php.net/mysqli)** or **[PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo)**.

But if you insist on using the `mysql_` functions you can use **[mysql_fetch_assoc](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc)** to get the details returned in an associative array key'd on field names.

```
$id= $_GET['id'];
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE id='$id'";
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
if (!$rs) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error(); //A bit of error checking
    exit;
}

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);

if($row){
  echo $row['field']; // An array key'd on the table's field names is returned
}
```

If a field in your `people` table is named `first_name` then that value would be stored in `$row['first_name']` in the returned associative array.

I assume `id` is a unique field and at most you expect one row returned.
If that is not the case use a loop with the condition `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))` to loop through all returned rows.

Answer (score -1):

You have to fetch result.

try like this:

```
$id= $_GET['id'];
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE id='$id'";
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['id']; //$row is an array of each row of your table
}
```

[see details](http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array)

`mysql_*` functions are deprecated you should switch to `mysqli_*` or `pdo`

Answer (score -1):

```
    $id= $_GET['id'];
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE id='$id'";
    $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($row);
      if($num > 0)
      {  
         foreach($row as $r) 
         {
         echo $r;          
         }
      }
      else
      {
         echo "No rows "
      }
```

This code will display the values .
**Note: mysql_query will be deprecated in later version of PHP. So better start with mysqli or PDO's in PHP.**