# how to select a row using an a unique ID from url

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have my home page list 20 rows from my database, now I want to create another page that will display the full details of one record when a link is clicked from the home page here is my code that displays 20 records:

```
<table class="table stats-table ">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">Latest Uploads</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            require_once 'dbconfig.php';
            $query = "SELECT musicID, musicName, musicUploader, musicDate FROM tbl_music ORDER BY musicDate DESC LIMIT 20";
            $stmt = $DBcon->prepare( $query );
            $stmt->execute();
            while ($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
            extract($row);
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $musicName; ?></td>
                <td align="center"><span class="label label-success"><em><b>By:</b> <?php echo $musicUploader; ?></em></span> &nbsp;&mdash;&nbsp;<?php echo $musicDate; ?></td>
                <td><h5><a href="music-details.php?music=<?php echo $musicID; ?>"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a></h5></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So please I don't know what to do in **music-details.php** the page I need help, please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$_GET['music']` will have the id to use on `music-details.php`

Comment: You are already correctly creating a link that passes the ID to `music-details` as a `$_GET` parameter. Simply check what your `$_GET['music']` parameter is on your second page and work from there. That will get you started :)

Comment: Please I need a code set of the `$_GET['music']` parameter. I have tried some that i got from google search they're not working please help me make a little code.  Thanks Obsidian

Comment: try to echo $_GET['music'] check if you are getting the right ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the working answer to this question and it have realy solved the problem here is my new code:

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = 'sql106.epizy.com';
$mysql_username = 'epiz_21612479';
$mysql_password = 'HPpc47590656';
$mysql_dbname = 'epiz_21612479_db';

$music = $_GET['music'];

try {

$pdo= new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password); 
     $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
     exit( $e->getMessage() );
}


try {

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl_music WHERE musicID = :id');
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $music);
$stmt->execute();

} catch (PDOException $e) {
     echo $e->getMessage();
}

/* optional method
foreach($stmt as $row) {
      echo $row['id'] . ' ' . $row['name'] . ' ' . $row['email'];
}
*/

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $id = $row['musicID'];
  $mn = $row['musicName'];
  $ma = $row['musicArtist'];
  $mu = $row['musicUploader'];
  $mf = $row['musicFile'];
  $ms = $row['musicSize'];
  $md = $row['musicDate'];
}


?>
```

and here is where the details will display:

**Artist:**

```
        <p><b>Uploader:</b> <?php echo $mu; ?></p>
        <p><b>Size:</b> <?php echo $ms; ?></p>
        <p><b>Date  Uploaded:</b> <?php echo $md; ?></p>
        <a href="downloads/<?php echo $mf; ?>" title="Downloadnow" class='btn btn-sm btn-danger'><i class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i> Download </a>
```

Thanks to all of you who tried to help me, I also got the answer from stackoverflow
The answer is here [How to retrieve details for a particular id from MYSQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495909/how-to-retrieve-details-for-a-particular-id-from-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
<?php
    require_once 'dbconfig.php';
    $query = "SELECT musicID, musicName, musicUploader, musicDate FROM tbl_music WHERE musicID = ?";
    $stmt = $DBcon->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->execute([(int)$_GET['music']]);
    $details=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

Comment: Hello **Obsidian** i have done that but it open the page but don't display any record in it `<?php
    require_once 'dbconfig.php';
    $music = $_GET['music'];
    $query = "SELECT musicName,musicFile FROM tbl_music WHERE musicID = ?";
    $stmt = $DBcon->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->execute([(int)$_GET['music']]); 
    $details=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>` What else can i add to it

Comment: you add html? like <b>Name:</b> <?php echo $details['musicName']; ?>

Comment: I did that but still nothing. Here is my code `<p><b>Artist:</b> <?php echo $row['musicArtist']; ?></p>
                <p><b>Uploader:</b> <?php echo $row['musicUploader']; ?></p>
                <p><b>Size:</b> <?php echo $row['musicSize']; ?></p>
                <p><b>Date  Uploaded:</b> <?php echo $row['musicDate']; ?></p>
                <a href="downloads/<?php echo $row['musicFile']; ?>" title="Downloadnow" class='btn btn-sm btn-danger'><i class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i> Download </a>` [https://starzhit.ga/music-details?music=5](https://starzhit.ga/music-details?music=5)

Comment: $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);